# Permutations of small and large elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm

If the array is : `2,3,7,9`; then the ways in which we can have permutations are:

```
2 7 3 9
2 9 3 7
3 7 2 9
3 9 2 7
7 9 2 3

so total ways are 5.
```

Here the restriction is :

1. Once an element is selected the next element must be larger than it.
2. The next element after this must be smaller than the previous one, and so on until the last element.

I have below code, but I am not able to get the logic for permutaions:

```js
let array = [2, 3, 7, 9];
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
let res = [];
let n = array.length;
let i = 0;
let j = n - 1;
let k = 0;
while (i < j) {
  res[k++] = array[i++];
  res[k++] = array[j--];
}
if (n % 2 != 0) {
  res[k++] = arr[i];
}

console.log(res);
```

Based on comments:

```
function Factorial(n) { 

    var res=1; 
      
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
        res = res * i; 
    return res; 
} 


let n = 4;
let A = [];
let C = [];
let a = Factorial(n);
for(let i=0; i<=n;i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
}
A[1] = 1;
for(let k=0; k<n; k++) {
    let b = Factorial(k)*Factorial(n-k);
    
    A[k] = a/b * A[k]*A[n-k]/2;
}
console.log(A);



prints [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: what is the wanted result?

Comment: @NinaScholz number of possible ways, so 5 in my example

Comment: What is "selected" element?

Comment: @MBo, element in the array.

Comment: Do you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation ?

Comment: @MBo, yes exactly

Comment: So, there is ample information there to get this count?

Comment: In inspiration of @MBo comment, there are some existing algorithms and implementations of these on the web in various languages. You could port one of them to js. Better than reinventing the wheel if time is of concern.

Comment: @trincot, I have an array as input and the given 2 restrictions, I need to print the possible count as output.

Comment: =) Or just use the known first counts: `1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 16, 61, 272, 1385, 7936, 50521, 353792, 2702765, 22368256, 199360981, 1903757312, 19391512145, 209865342976, 2404879675441, 29088885112832, 370371188237525, 4951498053124096, 69348874393137901, 1015423886506852352, 15514534163557086905, 246921480190207983616, 4087072509293123892361`, so for array of length 10 the answer will be 50521

Comment: @learner, I understand the question, and I understand that Wikipedia gives the formula to get this possible count. So why you don't implement that?

Comment: I don't believe this is an alternating permutation if the array can contain duplicate entries.

Comment: Good point @Gershom. Im seeing some conflicting info/solutions on the web. Maybe the terminology is mixed. But if the larger -> smaller pattern applies, then equal to is definitely out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of permutation is called [zigzag or alternating permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation)

It is known that the number of such permutations of `n` elements might be described with recurrent formula:

```
A(n+1) = Sum(k=0..n){C(n,k)*A(k)*A(n-k)} / 2
```

where `A(n)` is number of permutation of `n` items, `initial A[] = 1`, `C(n,k)` is [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

So we can fill array with calculated entries step-by step

```js
function cnk(n, k) {
  let res = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) 
    res = res * (n - i) / (i + 1);
  return res;
}

let m = 15;
let A = [1,1];
for (let i = 0; i < m-1; i++) {
  A.push(0);
}

for (let n = 2; n < m; n++) 
  for (let k = 0; k <= n; k++) 
    A[n + 1] += A[k] * A[n - k] * cnk(n, k) / 2;
    
console.log(A);
```

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 16, 61, 272, 1385, 7936, 50521, 353792, 2702765,
 22368256, 199360981, 1903757312]
```

Comment: But OP starts out with an array of arbitrary values

Comment: what is C and A here, I am trying to understand this.

Comment: @GetSet Just use 1..n as indices of source sorted array

Comment: @MBo, is A[0] is zero to start with? Also the input array values are not used in this formula?

Comment: `A(0)` would indeed be `0` (the result of summing over 0 summands)

Comment: @MBo, I added code based on your comments, but I am missing something because I am getting all zeros. can you please tell me what mistake I am doing

Comment: Please don't add information based on the answer back into your question. Keep it to the original question. If you have trouble with the implementation, then either put a link to a fiddle in the comments or ask a new question (after trying more)

Comment: @Gershom, if A[0] is zero , all elements A[1], A[2] ... etc are becoming zero, as we are doing multiplication here

Comment: You're right; the base case `A(1) = 1` is required to resolve that issue

Comment: @Gershom, I have already added that A[1] = 1, in my code, but getting same issue, all are zeros

Comment: @trincot, I added new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63567006/alternating-permutations

Comment: @learner You are too fast ;)  I added Python code to show implementation example