# Alternating permutations

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This post is extension to my previous post: [Permutations of small and large elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566268/permutations-of-small-and-large-elements)

I m trying to work on alternating permutations and here is my logic:

```js
function Factorial(n) { 
    
    var res=1; 
          
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
        res = res * i; 
    return res; 
} 
    
    
let n = 4;
let A = [];
let C = [];
let a = Factorial(n);
for(let i=0; i<=n;i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
}
A[1] = 1;
for(let k=0; k<n; k++) {
    let b = Factorial(k)*Factorial(n-k);
        
    A[k] = a/b * A[k]*A[n-k]/2;
}
console.log(A);
```

```
prints [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I am expecting A[n+1] = 5 for input n = 4 as per my previous post. But I am getting all zeros.
How to fix this issue.

Comment: `*A[n-k]` is `0`

Comment: You are not implementing the formula correctly. The referenced Wikipedia article has a SUM operation which you have not implemented. You need one more nested loop.

Comment: It prints `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Five zeros!

Comment: I added JS code in that post

Comment: I ran the JS code in that post.

Comment: @learner are you trying to find out all the given permission according to the rules?

Answer (score 0):

You did not implement the sum (∑) in the [formula of André](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation#Andr%C3%A9%27s_theorem) that your refer to.

I would also avoid calculating factorials as you will soon bump into a limitation of floating point precision. You can instead use the [triangle of Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Here is an implementation of an infinite generator of the A sequence. The demo prints the values of A[0] up to A[20]:

```js
function * andre() { // generator
    let pascal = [1];
    let a = [1, 1];
    yield a[0];
    
    let n = 1;
    while (true) {
        yield a[n];
        // Build the next row in Pascal's Triangle
        pascal[n] = 1;
        for (let i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            pascal[i] += pascal[i-1];
        }
        // Apply André's formula
        let sum = 0;
        for (let k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            sum += pascal[k] * a[k] * a[n-k]
        }
        a[++n] = sum / 2;
    }
}

// demo: display A[0] up to A[20]
let i = 0;
for (let a of andre()) {
    console.log(`A[${i++}] = ${a}`);
    if (i > 20) break;
}
```

As this sequence increases fast, you'll need higher precision soon. If you need *A[i]* for higher values of *i*, then use JavaScript's `BigInt` data type.